# how to convert shp and gis line and raster data to autocad (dwg or dxf) in QGIS or GRASS

Tags: shapefile, convert, autocad, dxf, dwg

I am trying to find out which is best free GIS program with ability to convert shp and line and raster files to files suitable for autocad (e.g. dwg and dxf).

I have QGIS and GRASS.

I get an error message that QGIS cannot save as dxf although it is a format in the options.

Comment: Show some sample data and the exact error message that you get. Saving vectors into DXF works for me with QGIS 2.6. Rasters AutoCAD can probably open from normal raster files like tiff or jpeg.

Answer (score 1):

BabaCAD with new ESRI shapefile add-on is all you need (freeware). You can also filter data in attribute table view and copy selection to a new layer.

Answer (score 1):

Use gdal (http://www.gdal.org) you won't be able to create dwg directly but you can create a dxf

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert raster to AutoCAD DXF/DWG. If you have georeferenced raster (e.g. GeoTiff) and AutoCAD Map, you can simply add the raster to your AutoCAD drawing.

Vector features can be exported to DXF from QGIS and GRASS, too. In QGIS you can use *Save as* from the popup menu of the layer or *Project/DXF Export* from the main menu. In GRASS use *v.out.dxf* command.